# multiple jQuery simple modal boxes

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

How would you utilize the jQuery simple modal box, for multiple instances on one page, with unique content for each description??

Would I use the `.this` function?

**html:**

```
    <div id='class-descriptions'>
      <a href='#' class='basic'>Description 1</a>
      <a href='#' class='basic'>Description 2</a>
      <a href='#' class='basic'>Description 3</a>
      <a href='#' class='basic'>Description 4</a>
    </div>

<div id="description1">description 1 content</div>
<div id="description1">description 2 content</div>
<div id="description1">description 3 content</div>
<div id="description1">description 4 content</div>
```

**js:**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // Load dialog on page load
    //$('#description').modal();

    // Load dialog on click
    $('#class-descriptions .class').click(function (e) {
        $('#description1').modal();

        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing that you need to know it's fix the html code, you cannot use the same id for the divs, also you need to bind in some way the element `a` with the element `div` which have the content

```
<div id='class-descriptions'>
  <a href='#' id="description-1" class='basic'>Description 1</a>
  <a href='#' id="description-2" class='basic'>Description 2</a>
  <a href='#' id="description-3" class='basic'>Description 3</a>
  <a href='#' id="description-4" class='basic'>Description 4</a>
</div>

<div id="content-1">description 1 content</div>
<div id="content-2">description 2 content</div>
<div id="content-3">description 3 content</div>
<div id="content-4">description 4 content</div>
```

Assuming that each element `a` it's refered to each `div` that would be a modal, maybe the code should be like this

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#class-descriptions .basic').click(function (e) {
        var aux = $(this).attr('id');
        aux = aux.replace('description','content');
        $(aux).modal();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`$('#class-descriptions .class')` is wrong. Use `.basic` instead of `.class`

Comment: Even u can use just $(.basic) if the only links with that class are these.